# Expression style View(..) using MVCContrib

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

Using MVCContrib you can easily do RedirectToAction calls such as

```
this.RedirectToAction( c => c.List() );
```

where List is an action result in said controller. Is there a way to do the same but using the "View" method instead? I.E

```
this.View( c => c.List(), viewModel );
```

Here's a trivial but complete example:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Profile()
{
    return View( new ProfileViewModel() )
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Profile( ProfilePostModel postModel )
{
    if( !ModelState.IsValid )
        return this.View( c => c.Profile(), postModel.MapToViewModel() );
    _service.Save(postModel.MapToDtoObject() );
    return this.RedirectToAction( c => c.SomeOtherAction() );
}
```

I've been searching around and haven't found anything relevant.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if such method exists in MVCContrib but it would be trivial to write one:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static ViewResult View<T>(
        this T controller, 
        Expression<Func<T, ActionResult>> expression, 
        object model
    ) where T : Controller
    {
        var mce = expression.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        if (mce == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        var result = new ViewResult();
        result.ViewName = mce.Method.Name;
        result.ViewData.Model = model;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin. I'm just getting into playing around with the expressions but that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no code that represents the view itself, I don't think this can be made out-of-the-box.
You can achieve something similar if you create conventions on how you choose which views are rendered.
You can get some ideas from [this post](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/06/29/how-we-do-mvc-view-models.aspx) Jimmy Bogard's blog.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen his post on ViewModels. I'm thinking that under the hood it would have to take the action I passed in an turn that into a string name and then call the built in View function, but was curious if there was something out there/in mvccontrib that already handle that... thanks for the feedback~